# Alternative for TYPE_KEYGUARD

Tags: android

Want to make an app that lock home screen and the only problem I have is that I can't block home button. I've found some information that `TYPE_KEYGUARD` can do it but it's deprecated.So,is there any alternative for this type which can block home button too?

Answer (score 0):

LockScreenSample-Disable HomeButton or HomeKey Event

https://github.com/DUBULEE/Android-LockScreenSample-DisableHomeButtonKey